# How to find Stall Time Asset Pack folder into user device

Tags: java, android-studio

My projet has more than 2 GB, so I had to use Play Asset Delivery to public it on Play Story. Now I need to know where is placed in user device the folder that contains the files of "install time asset pack". After the files are copied on user device, I have to add all them into an Array. I've found the "fast follow asset pack" folder in (/data/data/mypackage/files/assetpacks/fast_follow_asset_pack1/66/66/assets/) and I had add all of them. Howbeit can't do it with "install time asset pack" files because I do not know where they are. Please helpe-me, if you may. I´m using android Studio and Java.

Comment: Please, let me know if you did not understand my question or if you have no answer.